# .Net can't connect to mariadb database in docker container

Tags: c#, sql, .net, docker, mariadb

I'm trying to connect to my Mariadb database that's inside a Docker container. I've looked at Microsoft's documentation and searched on Google to find out why I'm getting an error message saying that there's nothing to retrieve from the database. It's strange because when I try to debug my code, it doesn't execute the lines that check the database. The error happens at the line "conn.Open();" and then it just stops. I can also see in Docker that it's getting a connection, so the connection string should be correct. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

This is the error message:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Object cannot be cast from DBNull to
> other types.'

Here is my code:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace DockerBase
{
    internal class UserDB
    {
        public bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                builder.Server = "localhost";
                builder.Port = 3306;
                builder.UserID = "root";
                builder.Password = "rootpassword";
                builder.Database = "userDB";

                using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = @username AND password = @password;";
                    int result = 0;

                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
                        result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                    }

                    bool isValid = (result > 0);
                    return isValid;
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error connecting to MySQL database: " + e.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my dockerfile also

```
FROM mariadb:latest

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=userDB
ENV MYSQL_USER=myuser
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypassword
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword

# Copy SQL scripts
COPY createUser.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

EXPOSE 3306
```

And also my sql code:

```
USE userDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;

CREATE TABLE users (
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('admin', 'admin');
```

In the terminal in Dockerhub I can see that a connection is being made:

> Aborted connection 3 to db: 'userDB' user: 'root' host: 'REMOVED' (Got an error reading communication packets)

Comment: `builder.Server = "localhost";` docker containers do not share `localhost`.

Comment: Please clarify, are you running your code locally or inside of docker container?

Comment: Also, can you connect to your db using some client, for example dbeaver or mysql workbench?

Comment: im running the code locally on my pc and i am able to connect to the container using mysql workbench and the ip 127.0.0.1 and port 3306

Comment: Yikes, this looks like a plain-text password. That's very bad, and one of those things that's too important to do wrong even for practice/learning/proof of concept code.

Comment: Also: that `cannot be cast from DBNull` error message can only be created by C# code **after** the query as already executed. Most likely, the result of the `COUNT(*)` SQL function is `NULL` rather than an integer.

Comment: tried removing the count and also tried reading the values from the database into a local variable and then comparing them. But the same error happens

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to connect to MariaDB after upgrade to version 10.11.5 from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77179294/failed-to-connect-to-mariadb-after-upgrade-to-version-10-11-5-from-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is something with using mariadb. When i press the login button again it then works, so something with the first connection now being completely establish. I changed the Dockerfile so that it uses the latest version of MySQL instead and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`builder.Server = "localhost";`

Change this line so that it contains your container name, not localhost, like following:

`builder.Server = "mysql-container-name";`

This is done due to docker containers not sharing localhost.

Comment: did not work. I tried changing to to builder.Server = "mysql-dockerbase-db-1"; and just got a MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'

Comment: Since OP clarified that code is run locally, and not inside of container, I believe your answer is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

We have this error message:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.'

Specifically, `DBNull` is **NOT** a concept the MySQL database knows about. It's a special value in the client **.Net** code used for representing `NULL`s returned from an SQL query. It's needed as a distinct item from the normal C# `null` reference because the primitive value types like `int` and `DateTime` don't have a `null` concept of their own to map to the corresponding SQL `Integer` and `Datetime` types, and the ADO.Net library pre-dates .Net nullable value types (`int?`, `DateTime?`, etc).

Therefore, the only way you could get this error is *after you've successfully run a query.* In other words, the connection worked and completed just fine, and the error occurs **after** the `ExecuteScalar()` call is finished.

Most likely, the `COUNT(*)` expression (somehow) results in `NULL` on the SQL side, which ADO.Net will express as `DBNull.Value` for C#, and [the `Convert.ToInt32()` function doesn't know what to do with this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9PM674).

This is different than not returning any rows. [The `ExecuteScalar()` function should return a basic C# `null` reference if the result set is empty](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_ExecuteScalar.htm), which is different from `DBNull`, if there are no rows.