# Failed to connect to MariaDB after upgrade to version 10.11.5 from c#

Tags: c#, mysql, mariadb

After upgrade on MariaDB to version **10.11.5** my connection code not working.

I use `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` but every time I receive a error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
```

My code is very simple on console application on c# just for testing.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

string cs = @"server=192.168.0.1;userid=uName;password=passwd;database=dbName";

using var con = new MySqlConnection(cs);
try
{
    con.Open();
    Console.WriteLine($"MySQL version : {con.ServerVersion}");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

What is the database connection alternative ?

**MySql.Data is version: 8.1.0**

All my API's applications stopped working ;(

Comment: Taken from the duplicate link posted in your last question.   https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/

Comment: The most popular MySQL provider in .NET is the truly open source MySqlConnector, not Oracle's buggy MySql.Data. Oracle's driver is full of serious bugs they explicitly said they won't fix. The maintenance schedule isn't good either. If you check MySql.Data's release date you'll realize that Oracle releases a new NuGet version along with new MySQL versions, not when fixes or features are ready to be released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pre-alpha version of package trying to fix this issue. You can try it and let me know if it helped.

NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Jf.MySql.Data.Collations/

Sources: https://github.com/jeffraska/Jf.MySql.Data.Collations/

The package is in "works on my computer" state. This means .NET framework 4.5, really old MySql.Data 6.9.7 library and latest MariaDB 10.11.4 currently available in Debian repository. So don't expect miracles.

It uses standard Command Interceptor functionality of MySql.Data library (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-interceptors.html) to alter all `SHOW COLLATION` queries and replacing it with `SHOW COLLATION WHERE id IS NOT NULL`.

Also the package have functionality to alter MySql.Data's internal charset mapping to allow reading utf8mb3 fields in pre 8.0.28 versions of MySql.Data .

Answer (score 4):

The latest versions of MySql.Data are not compatible with recent versions of MariaDB. According to [MySQL bug #109331](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109331), MariaDB is unsupported by Oracle's development team, and this incompatibility won't be fixed.

[MariaDB recommends](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqlconnector-for-ado-net/) using [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) (disclaimer: lead author). Usually it's a drop-in replacement for MySql.Data, but see [the documentation](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/) for information about some edge cases that may need to be handled.

Comment: MySqlConnector, aka not that Oracle s..... tuff

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB has recently fixed it, in 10.11.7 https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-31608. So, if you can't use the [recommended MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) connector, you'd need to upgrade the server.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by uninstalling the MySql.Data library and using the MySqlConnector (ver 2.3.5), but this requires a .NET version => 4.6.2.